# How can i check if imageview is empty or not

Tags: java, android

i have an application that has form and there is some fields the user should fill it ,i want to put the button "Next" disable until the user fill this fields.

the fields is:(iamgeView, EditText,Spinner..)

i know how to check the text Edit but how can i check if the user fill the image and spinner or not (image view will let the user choose an image from native gallery)

What i want: how can i check if the user fill the image and spinner or not?
this is my code to check the Edit Text

```
  private boolean checkEditText2(EditText edit) {
    return edit.getText().length() == 0;
}
```

Comment: i suppose you save the image somewhere when you return from the gallery?

Comment: you mean this ?    `  Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData(); CaPic.setImageURI(selectedImageUri);`

Comment: at some point, you were considering getting the image back to store it somewhere, weren't you ? can't you use the same method and check for null or something?

Answer (score 11):

In xml file your image have not `android:src=""` **and** `android:backgroud=""`

```
   if(null!=imgView.getDrawable())
     {
        //imageview has image
     }else{
       //imageview has no image  
     }
```

Comment: actually it have `android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_gallery" />`, should i delete it?

Comment: But if it has background?

Answer (score 0):

Despite what the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9707067/3345644) proposes, you should do the following instead:

```
publie static boolean hasNullOrEmptyDrawable(ImageView iv)
{
    Drawable drawable = iv.getDrawable();
    BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = drawable instanceof BitmapDrawable ? (BitmapDrawable)drawable : null;

    return bitmapDrawable == null || bitmapDrawable.getBitmap() == null;
}
```

See explanation in [my previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45702203/3345644).