# How to check if ImageView contains Bitmap or not?

Tags: java, android, android-camera, android-imageview, drawable

I am implementing if a `ImageView` has bitmap then it should save the image from imageview to internal memory ,otherwise set another bitmap in internal memory of application.
here is code:_

```
 croppedImage = cropImageView.getCroppedImage();
                 croppedImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.croppedImageView);
                croppedImageView.setImageBitmap(croppedImage);@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.btn_save:
            counter++;
            if(croppedImageView.getDrawable() != null)
            {
                System.out.println("nullllllllllllll");

                try {
                    Bitmap photo = ((BitmapDrawable)croppedImageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
                    FileOutputStream mFileOutStream1 = openFileOutput("IMG" + counter + ".png", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                    photo.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, mFileOutStream1);} 
                catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();}
                }else{
                  System.out.println("notttttnullllllllllllll");
                  try {
                     FileOutputStream mFileOutStream1 = openFileOutput("IMG" + counter + ".png", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, mFileOutStream1);
                  } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                  }

                }
Editor editor = def.edit();
            editor.putInt("value", counter);
            editor.commit();
    break;

        default:
            break;
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can check it as follows:

```
boolean hasDrawable = (croppedImageView.getDrawable() != null);
if(hasDrawable) {
    // imageView has image in it
}
else {
    // no image assigned to image view
}
```

Just check only Bitmap value as below :

```
if(bitmap == null) {
    // set the toast for select image
} else {
    uploadImageToServer();
}
```

Comment: boolean hasDrawable = (croppedImageView.getDrawable() != null);
   if(hasDrawable) {
      System.out.println("drawableeeeee  "+hasDrawable);
   }
   else {
    System.out.println("drawableeeeee  "+hasDrawable);
   }


i implemented  this code to check out but it also not giving any response.

Comment: what do you mean by _"not giving any response"_? Do you see other output from `System.out.println`? See http://stackoverflow.com/q/2220547/827110

Comment: No its not printing anything .

Comment: Please use `Log.d` to log output to `logcat` or use a debugger to verify. Also click on the link I have posted in the comment and read it.

Answer (score 1):

The [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20324098/3345644) **is not correct** for at least one case: when you previously set `ImageView`s `Bitmap` to `null` via:

```
imageView.setImageBitmap(null);
```

actually **it would NOT set the internal `Drawable` to `null`**. So, the proposed in the accepted answer check will give you incorrect result.

You can easily find out what's going on in the `ImageView` [source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.1.1_r1/android/widget/ImageView.java#ImageView.setImageBitmap%28android.graphics.Bitmap%29):

```
 public void setImageBitmap(Bitmap bm) {
     // if this is used frequently, may handle bitmaps explicitly
     // to reduce the intermediate drawable object
     setImageDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(mContext.getResources(), bm));
 }
```

Meaning that instead of setting its internal `Drawable` to `null`, it sets it to a newly created `BitmapDrawable` with `null` `Bitmap`.

Therefore, **the correct method of checking whether an `ImageView` has somewhat meaningful `Drawable` is** something like:

```
publie static boolean hasNullOrEmptyDrawable(ImageView iv)
{
    Drawable drawable = iv.getDrawable();
    BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = drawable instanceof BitmapDrawable ? (BitmapDrawable)drawable : null;

    return bitmapDrawable == null || bitmapDrawable.getBitmap() == null;
}
```

Moreover, looking at this behavior in the source code, one might suppose that `null` `Drawble` is something Android SDK developers try to avoid. That's why you should avoid relying on `getDrawable() == null` check in your code at all.