# Check whether ImageView has only attached src drawable in Xml or later attached Image dynamically from activity?

Tags: android, imageview, android-bitmap

I have an ImageView in xml like this, and it has drawable **globe1** attached in xml :

```
                 <ImageView
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    android:id="@+id/ppImageView"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="200dp"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/globe1"
                    
                    />
```

Then I set an image bitmap dynimacally from java in that ImageView :

```
ppImageView.setImageBitmap(ppBitmap);
```

So, my question is how do I check that **ppImageView** contains **globe1** or  **ppBitmap** ?

I have checked this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20324048/how-to-check-if-imageview-contains-bitmap-or-not/20324098#20324098), but, seems that it does not fit my situation.

Answer (score 0):

Alhamdulillah, I have found the solution. What I do that, I have attached tag in xml:

```
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    android:id="@+id/iv_uphoto"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="200dp"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/globe1"
                    android:tag="globe1"
                    />
```

And When I Attached Image dynamically, I also set another tag :

```
 ppImageView.setImageBitmap(ppBitmap);
  ppImageView.setTag("ppImageView");
```

Then I check the Tag this Way :

```
if(hasImage(ppImageView, "ppImageView" )){

            System.out.println("ppImageTag: "+(String)ppImageView.getTag());
                System.out.println("Image Attached in ppImageView");
                // now do your Work : 
                

        }else {
            Toast.makeText(ProfilePageTeacher.this,"Please Attach Appropriate PassPort Image",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
        }
```

And the hasImage method as follows :

```
private boolean hasImage(@NonNull ImageView view, String tag) {

        String previousTag = (String) view.getTag();

        return previousTag.equalsIgnoreCase(tag);


    }
```